# Colour Picker not working in knockoutJS template tabs

Tags: knockout.js

Hi I am trying to use a jQuery colour picker within my knockout template, the colour picker I got from http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-miniColors/. I have a tab selector (which has 3 knockout templates) it rotates through each template as the user selects the tabs done by knockout and the colour picker appears on the first one but as i go through the tabs it doesn't add in the colour picker in the remaining two, even if i go back to the original tab after going through all the tabs (where it originally worked).

I get no error in the console, but even if i try and do a javascript alert from within the knockout templates (2 and 3) that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<script id="Links" type="text/html">
    <div id="linksTemplate">
        <section class="well span7">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Links</legend>
                <label class="inline">
                    <span class="formLabel">Border Colour</span>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: settings.links.style.stroke" class="minicolors" data-control="saturation" />
                </label>

                <label class="inline">
                    <span class="formLabel">Border Width</span>
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: settings.links.style.stroke_width" />
                </label>
            </fieldset>
        </section>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hello');
        });
    </script>
</script>
```

Comment: Without any code it is impossible to find out what is causing your problem. Please extend your question with the relevant code parts. Ideally a simplified JSFiddle would be the best which shows your actual problem.

Comment: I can't link to the JSFiddle as there are lots of files which I am unable to put online, I have added some of the code above, there are 3 knockout templates Nodes, Links, Labels (which appear in that order)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a binding for the knockout mapping. I am using the same color picker and got this to work. Can't tell you if this is the best solution as it was kind of a trial and error. I'm not very familiar with knockout but it works.

This is the binding function you need:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.minicolors = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {

        var options = allBindingsAccessor().defaultSettings || {};

  var funcOnSelectColor = function () {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
  observable($(element).minicolors("value"));
}
//-- also change event to hide
options.hide = funcOnSelectColor;

$(element).minicolors(options);

//handle the field changing
ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", funcOnSelectColor);

//handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
  $(element).minicolors("destroy");
});

},
 update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
   var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

   var current = $(element).minicolors("value");
   if (value - current !== 0) {
     $(element).minicolors("value", value);
   }
 }
};
```

This is how you use it:

```
<input class="minicolors" data-position="default" style="padding: 2px; height: 20px;" data-bind="minicolors: MYKNOCKOUTBINDING, defaultSettings: {}" />
```

Hope this helps